# Process.Start not starting

Tags: vb.net, shell, process, cmd

I'm trying to execute a 3rd party application, called from a .cmd batch file, called from a self-hosted WCF service. Like this:

WCF --> .cmd --> 3rd party app

For whatever reason, using the Shell command doesn't work fully. It will call the .cmd file, but the 3rd party app won't kick off (I know the .cmd is firing because I have before/after ECHO statements populating a log file). If I double-click the .cmd file from explorer, the 3rd party app will start just fine. So, I figured, maybe try something besides the Shell command from my WCF service.

So I tried the following code, but it won't kick off the .cmd file at all (echo statements not firing). What am I missing here?

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C " & System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ExStream_CMD_File_Path"))

Dim proc As New Process()
proc.StartInfo = psi
proc.Start()
proc.WaitForExit()
```

The path in the app.config file is valid (just double-checked). Is there anything wrong with the above code?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: How do you know it doesn't start.

Comment: As said in the post, the echo statements are not writing to the log file.

Comment: So the before statement is firing but not the after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my second edit to the question here:

[Simple software testing tool - VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635020/simple-software-testing-tool-vb-net/5635703#5635703)

Basically you need to make sure to double-escape the quotes around the command that you're executing with `/C`