# StandardInput problems with Process class in c#

Tags: c#, redirect

I would like to execute a shell line using---> Process myProcess = new Process();

the line is something like:

```
 pathMyProgram -options < file.txt
```

I have done

```
Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName=pathMyProgram;
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments=-optins < file.txt
```

...
but it doesn`t work ( due to the redirection...)

So after reading I have tried

```
enter code here

Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName=pathMyProgram;
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments=-optins 

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pProcess.Start();
pProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(file.txt);
```

and it continue without working, any help?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace :

```
pProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine(file.txt);
```

with something like:

```
try
{
    pProcess.StandardInput.Write(File.ReadAllText("file.txt"));
}
finally
{
    pProcess.StandardInput.Close();
}
```

That's assuming you can read the entire file into memory easily.  If it's a large file you'll want to read it a line at a time and pass it to the

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using `"strings"`?

```
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "pathMyProgram";
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-optins < file.txt";
```

Also note you will need to escape backslashes, like this:

```
"C:\\Path\\To\\Program.exe"
```

You should better read some beginners guide to C# to grasp the basics. (Unless I missed something in the meaning of your question.)

Comment: As the OP stated himself, you cannot use 'Arguments' for input redirection.

Comment: You can use `@"C:\Path\To\Program.exe"` as well to make it literal, I find it easier to read and less error prone

Comment: Well the primary problem seems to be completely broken C# code syntax at the first place.

Comment: @John Yes, you are right; however, I tried to omit another string literal syntax in my answer at the first place.

Comment: the code in c# is not completely, there is just the part i consider explicit for the problem...¬¬

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse shell redirection and the `cmd.exe` program. They look and act similar but are still different things. Arguments such as `<` and `>` are specific to `cmd.exe` If you pass these into your process they will be passed literally and you will need to parse them manually.

See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5635020/simple-software-testing-tool-vb-net/5635703#5635703), specifically EDIT 2 and 3. Also checkout [Raymond Chen's blog post on it here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/16/598893.aspx)

Comment: It looks like you didn't read the second half of the OP.  He realized this himself, but he's just been copy/pasting code from various sources without understanding what it does and clearly this is causing him problems.

Comment: I read it but although I think the OP realized the potential problem I don't think he actually understands it. His edit still looks like he's trying to perform the redirection in a different way. The posts I linked to show how to pass these to `cmd.exe` with the `/C` switch which should do what he's trying to do.

Comment: I did the first one without any redirection, just commands and I have no problems, the problems came when I tried the redirection. and i wrote what I found..and like it doesn`t work I asked there..now I am reading the Raymond Chen's blog post, the only one who trie to help and not to critize

Comment: @jobormo, I don't think anyone was trying to criticize you directly. On this site we get many, many questions from people with skills all over the place. Some are crazy awesome ninja programmers and some are just beginners. Unfortunately there isn't an easy way for us to determine that with newer users. So when we see code that won't even compile the first thing we do is try to correct that problem. Believe it or not, there a many posts every day that are solved just by fixing the compiling errors. Missing quotes, slashes, etc.