# How to open cmd everytime using C# Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-core, kestrel

I want to run bat file on using `System.Diagnostics` and I did. But I have a problem.

```cs
public static void RunMiningProgram(string appPath, string batFilePath)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = $"{appPath}\\{batFilePath}";
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = appPath;
            p.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
var path = @"D:\PROJECTS\ies-disk\asp-net-core\IesDisk.ApiProcess\wwwroot\C.bat";
var appath = @"D:\PROJECTS\ies-disk\asp-net-core\IesDisk.ApiProcess\wwwroot";

RunMiningProgram(apppath, path);
```

[image]

When we run the program, the results of the bat files appear on the console screen that Kestrel opens. How can I open two different cmd applications instead of showing them in the Kestrel console.

if i visualize my question i want two different cmd screens to open.

[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to start new command prompts. Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36776854/running-a-cmd-command-from-c-sharp

Comment: you do not want to see it on screen (probably  this is an issue for sure) ? what is the issue ?

Comment: The issue is when I run the bat file using ```process.start(batfilepath)```. it is not opening a new cmd screen. But I want to it.

Comment: @BurakErgün probably its open it, but under the account of asp.net - remember this is server side programming - and who is going to monitor this commands on server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void RunMiningProgram(string appPath, string batFilePath)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        Process.Start("cmd.exe", $"/c start /D {appPath} {appPath}{batFilePath}");
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunMiningProgram("C:\\", "hello.bat");
}
```

Comment: ```$"/c start /D {appPath} {appPath}{batFilePath}"```.What's for  ```/D ```

Comment: @Burak specifying working directory I think. Check cmd start documentation. It let's you not have to specify it by setting p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory